# Linq group by month/year with empty months for past 12 months

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How would I get this query to get the monthly count data for the past 12 months?  I don't want to hard code the range, I want to use the current date `DateTime.Now` and get all the data for the past 12 months from that.  I am trying to avoid adding a calendar table to the database and do this just using `LINQ`.

Some months might not have any data but I still need a count of `0` for those.

For example.  If my data contains

```
Date     Count
12/2/2013, 4
10/1/2014, 1
11/5/2014, 6
```

The results should be, using the current date of 11/9/2014

```
11/2013, 0
12/1013, 4
 1/2014, 0
 2/2014, 0
 3/2014, 0
 4/2014, 0
 5/2014, 0
 6/2014, 0
 7/2014, 0
 8/2014, 0
 9/2014, 0
10/2014, 1
11/2014, 6
```

I can't get it to work.  I think it's how I'm using `Range` but I'm not sure.

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime yearAgo = DateTime.Now.Subtract(ts);

var changesPerYearAndMonth =
    from year in Enumerable.Range(yearAgo.Year, 1)
    from month in Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
    let key = new { Year = year, Month = month }
    join revision in list on key
          equals new { revision.LocalTimeStamp.Year, 
                       revision.LocalTimeStamp.Month } into g
    select new { GroupCriteria = key, Count = g.Count() };
```

I have modified the answer from this this link as a starting point.
[Linq: group by year and month, and manage empty months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245876/linq-group-by-year-and-month-and-manage-empty-months)

I just found this article that is the same question but unanswered
[Linq - group by datetime for previous 12 months - include empty months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188069/linq-group-by-datetime-for-previous-12-months-include-empty-months)

Comment: Is the `LocalTimeStamp.Year` property always equal to `2013` ? Is the `LocalTimeStamp.Month` property always in the range `[1, 12]` ? It looks like you wanted to have `Enumerable.Range(yearAgo.Year, 2)` ... ?

Comment: No, it is the past year from the current date.

Comment: You could use `ToLookup` instead of `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the past twelve months, use

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var months = Enumerable.Range(-12, 12)
    .Select(x => new { 
        year = now.AddMonths(x).Year, 
        month = now.AddMonths(x).Month });
```

To be safe you should first move 'now' to the start of the month to avoid any end-of-month effects with `AddMonth`.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
now = now.Date.AddDays(1-now.Day);
```

Complete example:-

```
 var list = new [] {
            new { LocalTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("12/2/2013"), count = 4},
            new { LocalTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("10/1/2014"), count = 1 },
            new { LocalTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("11/5/2014"), count = 6}
        };

        var now = DateTime.Now;
        now = now.Date.AddDays(1-now.Day);
        var months = Enumerable.Range(-12, 13)
            .Select(x => new { 
                year = now.AddMonths(x).Year, 
                month = now.AddMonths(x).Month });

        var changesPerYearAndMonth =
            months.GroupJoin(list, 
                m => new {month = m.month, year = m.year}, 
                revision => new { month = revision.LocalTimeStamp.Month,
                                  year = revision.LocalTimeStamp.Year},
                (p, g) => new {month = p.month, year = p.year, 
                               count = g.Sum(a => a.count)});


        foreach (var change in changesPerYearAndMonth)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(change.month + " " + change.year +" " + change.count);
        }
```

Comment: I am not clear how to use this with the other query results.  Would I include it with `from` in the linq query?

Comment: -1 It isn't clear enough how to use this. Especially with Linq to EF or Linq to SQL, which would require a `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a 3-way join, you just need to filter your data before grouping.

1) Query expression syntax

```
// since your list item type was not posted, anyway same access as your LocalTimeStamp property
list = new List<DateTime>();
DateTime aYearAgo = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
var dateslastYear = from date in list
                 where date > aYearAgo
                 group date by new { date.Year, date.Month } into g
                 select new { GroupCriteria = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

2) Chained

```
dateslastYear = list.Where (d=>d>aYearAgo)
                    .GroupBy (date=>new{date.Year, date.Month });
```

3) If you want grouping by year/month pairs, including records of not existent entries, and also omitting those pairs that are older than a year occurring with the joined `Enumerable.Range` call:

```
  var thisYearPairs = from m in Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.Now.Month)
                      select new { Year = DateTime.Now.Year, Month = m };
  var lastYearPairs = from m in Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Month, 12 - DateTime.Now.Month + 1)
                      select new { Year = DateTime.Now.Year - 1, Month = m };
  var ymOuter = from ym in thisYearPairs.Union(lastYearPairs)
                join l in list on new { ym.Year, ym.Month } equals new { l.Year, l.Month } into oj
                from p in oj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { a = ym, b = p == null ? DateTime.MinValue : p };
  var ymGroup = from ym in ymOuter
                group ym by ym into g
                select new { GroupCriteria = g.Key.a, Count = g.Key.b == DateTime.MinValue ? 0 : g.Count() };
```

Comment: The data might be empty for some months in the past year but I still need to it return a count of `0` for those.  I think that's what `Range` does but I'm not sure.  Does your answer address this?  I'm sorry if that didn't come across in my title but that's an important part of this questions.  That's what the "empty months" means and it's also part of the link I included.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the range for the 12 months of last year only but you actually want the last twelve months.

You can do this using a `Enumerable.Range` and the `AddMonths` method:

```
var changesPerYearAndMonth =
    from month in Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
    let key = new { Year = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-month).Year, Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-month).Month }
    join revision in list on key
            equals new
            {
                revision.LocalTimeStamp.Year,
                revision.LocalTimeStamp.Month
            } into g
    select new { GroupCriteria = key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int YearDiff(DateTime a, DateTime b)
{
    return (int) Math.Floor((a.Year + a.Month / 100.0 + a.Day / 10000.0) - (b.Year + b.Month / 100.0 + b.Day / 10000.0));
}
```